# Spring: how to rollback declarative transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, jpa

In this example, I don't know how to do rollback the transaction if a condition is verified. This is a Spring MVC application with JPA + Hibernate for persistence

In CartController:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/buy",method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public String buy(){
  CartDAO.buy();
  return "redirect:/";
 }//buy
```

In CartDAOImpl

```
@Transactional
public class CartDAOImpl implements CartDAO {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public void buy(){
 ....
 if(x !=y) throw new MyException();
 em.persist(Item);
 ....
}
}
```

In applicationContext-servlet.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
```

What's the best solution to this problem? Sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare in the `@Transactional` that you want Spring to performa a rollback when your `MyException` is thrown:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=MyException.class)
```

Comment: @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="Item quantity  terminated in database") public class MyException extends RuntimeException { } .Is it right?

Comment: You do not need your `MyException` to extend `RuntimeException` if you explicitly declare it in the `@Transactional`, as I have described.

Comment: So, I remove only "extends RuntimeException"?
 
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="Item quantity terminated in database") public class MyException extends { } .

Comment: An exception have to extends Throwable

Comment: @Alex Your MyException has to be an exception, of course. Try with `MyException extends Exception`

Comment: Is It better to create an unchecked exception or a checkedException with @Transactional(rollbackFor=MyException.class)?

Comment: Is it true that Spring prefer unchecked exception?

Comment: @Alex This is a much broader question that could be discussed for hours, and it finally **depends on you** (specially if your exception is called `MyException` ;). The point is: you can use the `rollbackFor=MyException.class` independently if it's checked or unchecked. It's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

From Spring documentation about rolling back declarative transactions:

> In its **default configuration, the Spring Framework’s transaction infrastructure code only marks a transaction for rollback in the case of runtime, unchecked exceptions**; that is, when the thrown exception is an instance or subclass of RuntimeException. ( Errors will also - by default - result in a rollback). Checked exceptions that are thrown from a transactional method do not result in rollback in the default configuration.
>
> You can configure exactly which Exception types mark a transaction for rollback, including checked exceptions. The following XML snippet demonstrates how you configure rollback for a checked, application-specific Exception type.

Source: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-rolling-back

Comment: If I inserted PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor in In applicationContext-servlet.xml,  Is MyException  unchecked?

Comment: Checked/unchecked are types of exceptions in Java, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html

Comment: I know these type of exceptions. But I don't know how to force the rollback.

Comment: Isn't the documentation clear? You just need to throw an unchecked exception. What is the code for MyException?

Comment: Are you referring to the status code?Or at the class code?
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
reason="Item quantity database terminated")
public class MyException extends RuntimeException {
}

Comment: Yes, this should work, you don't need to do anything else. Can you confirm it is not working? Can you add logs transaction manager (turn on debug , e.g. `log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG`?

Comment: Do I remove PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor?Do I declare the bean MyException in applicationContext-servlet.xml? If I write throw new MyException, the bean is not managed by Spting. Is it true?

Comment: PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor serves for different purpose, has nothing to do with a rollback. Your code is correct, when you do `throw new MyException()` the transaction should be rolled back. Is this not happening?

Comment: Is It better to create an unchecked exception or a checkedException with @Transactional(rollbackFor=MyException.class)?

Comment: That's up to you, I would go with unchecked exception (that's kind of convention in Spring and I prefer convention over configuration).

Comment: But with unchecked exception, if i want to display a error page I can't do that

Comment: Why not? What does your exception handler look like?

Comment: I want that when the exception occurs, the user is redirected to a  jsp error page

Comment: That's a separate issue, if your transaction is now being rolled back, you should accept the answer that helped you and open a new question.